# CSS - aspect-ratio: not working in Safari browser

Tags: css, safari

```css
.test {
    width: 20%;
    background: red;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

`aspect-ratio: 1/1;` It works fine in other browsers except safari. But this code doesn't work in Safari. I was using macOS 11.2. I have now updated to macOS 11.5.2. As far as I know it supports safari but I could not fully understand the problem. Thank you from now. If there is any missing information, I will add it if you let me know.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=aspect-ratio

Comment: @MaggieCody Thanks for your answer. I skipped Safari 15. I understand the situation. If you explain this in a separate answer, I'll upvote your answer. If you don't want it, I'll write the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I added an answer :)

Comment: Note: if you're having trouble, try updating iOS to 15. On iOS, Safari version matches the iOS version. And Safari 14< doesn't support it (or hides it behind an experimental flag in the settings). I hadn't installed 15 yet because of the bugs, and was confused why `aspect-ratio` wasn't working on my site. This should fix it for iOS Safari, Chrome, etc because they all use the same system installation of WebKit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

aspect-ratio as a css property is not supported in Safari prior to Safari 15, but the use of media queries with aspect-ratio `@media: (aspect-ratio: 1/1)` is supported: https://caniuse.com/?search=aspect-ratio

Comment: This feature is deprecated/obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: @lokarkristina You should provide a source for such a claim. Could not find any informations about being obsolete or deprecated on the Mozilla Web Doc Site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio

Comment: @Jan I agree, I would tell myself the same today. I don't remember adding this comment, looking at it now it seems like it was directed at something else, tbh. ‍♂️
For some reason, I can't edit the comment, so I'm sorry.

Answer (score 11):

You can add a fallback for that, this padding hack works for me

```
.test {
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    // Fallback
    @supports not (aspect-ratio: 16 / 9) {
    &::before {
      float: left;
      padding-top: 56.25%;
      content: "";
    }

    &::after {
      display: block;
      content: "";
      clear: both;
    }
  }
}
```

Other aspects ratio:

- 1:1 aspect ratio = 1 / 1 = 1 = `padding-top: 100%`
- 4:3 aspect ratio = 3 / 4 = 0.75 = `padding-top: 75%`
- 3:2 aspect ratio = 2 / 3 = 0.66666 = `padding-top: 66.67%`
- 16:9 aspect ratio = 9 / 16 = 0.5625 = `padding-top: 56.25%`

---

**Edit:**
I found this tool it helped me alot for other different aspect ratios
https://ratiobuddy.com/

Answer (score 2):

Cheeky SCSS mixin ..

```
@mixin aspect($width: 16, $height: 9) {
    aspect-ratio: $width / $height;

    @supports not (aspect-ratio: $width / $height) {
        &::before {
            content: '';
            float: left;
            padding-top: calc((#{$height} / #{$width}) * 100%);
        }

        &::after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me:

```css
.box {
  width: 20vw;
  height: calc(20vw * 1/1);
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```

1. Set the "width" of your choosing. In this case, we'll set our width to "20vw"

> width: 20vw;

2. Then, we'll create the "aspect-ratio" through the "height" property by multiplying the "width" and the desired "aspect-ratio" in fraction through "calc". In this case, we'll set the aspect-ratio to "1/1"

> height: calc(20vw * 1/1);

Here is a quick example on how to create different aspect-ratios:

1:1

> height: calc(width * 1/1);

3:2

> height: calc(width * 2/3);

4:3

> height: calc(width * 3/4);

16:9

> height: calc(width * 9/16);